# QGIS Geometry Generator - Connecting Points with Lines - with a 'one to many' relationship

Tags: qgis, geometry, geometry-generator

I'm working with  QGIS 3.12 and have two large point shapefiles (buildings/barns and wetlands) that I want to connect with lines via the geometry generator. I've found a function called get_feature() that will connect the points in the correct way but the get_feature() function only selects the first in a one to many relationship.

See example screenshot. The blue wetland dot is only connecting to one of the four building dots.

The script I have currently is:

```
make_line(    geometry(get_feature('barns', 'wID', '3809' ))  ,  geometry(get_feature('wetland_matrix', 'InputID', '3809' ))      )
```

I need to connect all four, not just the one!

[image: example of selection]

Comment: I think you need to define a relation firstly. Once the relation is defined you will need to try your expression with  a relation aggregate. I am not near a computer to test this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it seems like your barns and wetlands have a `matching ID` field (`wID` and `inputID`) and a `N (barns) to 1 (wetlands) relationship`. If so, you can do it easily, by setting up a geometry generator style on your barns (point) layer:

```
make_line($geometry,centroid(geometry(get_feature('wetland','inputID',attribute($currentfeature,'wID')))))
```

[image]

[image]